# Split text and find the common words in a Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working on Scala with Spark and I have a dataframe including two columns with text.

Those columns are with the format of "term1, term2, term3,..." and I want to create a third column with the common terms of the two of them.

For example

```
Col1 
orange, apple, melon
party, clouds, beach

Col2
apple, apricot, watermelon
black, yellow, white
```

The result would be

```
Col3
1
0
```

What I have done until now is to create a udf that splits the text and get the intersection of the two columns.

```
val common_terms = udf((a: String, b: String) => if (a.isEmpty || b.isEmpty) {
      0
    } else {
      split(a, ",").intersect(split(b, ",")).length
    })
```

And then on my dataframe

```
val results = termsDF.withColumn("col3", common_terms(col("col1"), col("col2"))
```

But I have the following error

```
Error:(96, 13) type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
      split(a, ",").intersect(split(b, ",")).length
```

I would appreciate any help since I am new in Scala and just trying to learn from online tutorials.

EDIT:

```
val common_authors = udf((a: String, b: String) => if (a != null || b != null) {
      0
    } else {
      val tempA = a.split( ",")
      val tempB = b.split(",")
      if ( tempA.isEmpty || tempB.isEmpty ) {
        0
      } else {
        tempA.intersect(tempB).length
      }
    })
```

After the edit, if I try `termsDF.show()` it runs. But if I do something like that `termsDF.orderBy(desc("col3"))` then I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
val common_terms = udf((a: String, b: String) => if (a.isEmpty || b.isEmpty) {
      0
    } else {
        var tmp1 = a.split(",")
        var tmp2 = b.split(",")
      tmp1.intersect(tmp2).length
    })

val results = termsDF.withColumn("col3", common_terms($"a", $"b")).show
```

split(a, ",") its a spark column functions.
You are using an udf so you need to use string.split() wich is a scala function

After edit: change null verification to == not !=

Comment: I have a `java.lang.NullPointerException` and it looks it is on the first line of the code (the `common_terms` definition

Comment: @Tasos on one of your columns you have a null value, before checking for isEmpty check for null too

Comment: if (a == null || b == null) not !=
Your condition is wrong

Answer (score 1):

In Spark 2.4 sql, you can get the same results without UDF. Check this out:

```
scala> val df = Seq(("orange,apple,melon","apple,apricot,watermelon"),("party,clouds,beach","black,yellow,white"), ("orange,apple,melon","apple,orange,watermelon")).toDF("col1","col2")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: string, col2: string]

scala>

scala> df.createOrReplaceTempView("tasos")

scala> spark.sql(""" select col1,col2, filter(split(col1,','), x -> array_contains(split(col2,','),x) ) a1 from tasos """).show(false)
+------------------+------------------------+---------------+
|col1              |col2                    |a1             |
+------------------+------------------------+---------------+
|orange,apple,melon|apple,apricot,watermelon|[apple]        |
|party,clouds,beach|black,yellow,white      |[]             |
|orange,apple,melon|apple,orange,watermelon |[orange, apple]|
+------------------+------------------------+---------------+
```

If you want the size, then

```
scala> spark.sql(""" select col1,col2, filter(split(col1,','), x -> array_contains(split(col2,','),x) ) a1 from tasos """).withColumn("a1_size",size('a1)).show(false)
+------------------+------------------------+---------------+-------+
|col1              |col2                    |a1             |a1_size|
+------------------+------------------------+---------------+-------+
|orange,apple,melon|apple,apricot,watermelon|[apple]        |1      |
|party,clouds,beach|black,yellow,white      |[]             |0      |
|orange,apple,melon|apple,orange,watermelon |[orange, apple]|2      |
+------------------+------------------------+---------------+-------+


scala>
```